# How to get last position of a character in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, lastindexof

I want to get last occurrence from multiple occurrences of a character in LibreOffice Calc.

For e.g. I have a string `abc1ba2ac2adeaa43add`. Now if I am searching for `a` it should return 18.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex:

```
=SEARCH("a[^a]*$"; CELL)
```

To search for another character than a, simply replace both a's with the character you want  to search for.

- http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=20344

Comment: That's a link to OpenOffice. LibreOffice doesn't use regex patterns in its SEARCH function.

Comment: Just in case anyone finds this - LibreOffice does use REGEX in formulas, but only after you enable it in Options under LibreOffice Calc -> Calculate -> Formulae Wildcards

Answer (score 2):

here's one that i cooked up recently - it answers the question without using regex (which for some reason, i couldn't get to work with libreoffice 4.3.1.2)

```
=FIND("+|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","+|",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","")))))
```

basically, it does the following:

1. replace the last instance of a particular search string with a marker

   SUBSTITUTE( 
    A1, "a", "+|", 
    (LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a",""))))
   )
2. find the index of the marker

   FIND( "+|", ... )

*- or to return the string to the right of 'a' -*

```
=MID(A1, FIND("+|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","+|", (LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","")))))+1, LEN(A1))
```

in this example, "a" is the last instance of a string you're looking for and "+|" is a placeholder that musn't already exist in the string you are searching

everything trailing the spec'd string is returned by the call to mid

Comment: Thanks - this was perfect for extracting the file extension from a file name. I just changed the references to "a" to "."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex solution that works out of the box with LibreCalc:

```
=LEN(<CELL>) - LEN(REGEX(<CELL>, "<CHAR>[^<CHAR>]*$")) + 1
```

It will use the `REGEX` function to get all text after the last occurrence of `<CHAR>` in `<CELL>`  and substract its length from the length of the whole string.

For direct copy/paste:

```
=LEN("abc1ba2ac2adeaa43add") - LEN(REGEX("abc1ba2ac2adeaa43add", "a[^a]*$")) + 1
```

And here is a solution to also support terms/words instead of single characters:

```
=LEN(<CELL>) - LEN(REGEX(<CELL>, <TERM> & "(?![\s\S]*" & <TERM> & ").*")) + 1
```

Or for direct copy/paste and the term `ad` which appears twice in the example string:

```
=LEN("abc1ba2ac2adeaa43add") - LEN(REGEX("abc1ba2ac2adeaa43add", "ad" & "(?![\s\S]*" & "ad" & ").*")) + 1
```